# Build a SKOS Reasoner rule-based

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, inference, clips, reasoning

I have to build a reasoner for ontologies SKOS to reason with rules made ​​in CLIPS / Jess. I want to have simple forms of automated reasoning.
I could not find anything specifically to help me create a reasoner for ontologies with rules, not even something similar to try to replicate some of the functionality in CLIPS.

Comment: I must first translate the SKOS ontologies in rule and facts Clips/Jess and after I could do with another set of inference rules that lead to simple forms of reasoning.

Comment: Same question posted (and answered) at answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11400/build-a-skos-reasoner-rule-based